# PHP if wrong output

Tags: php, file-io

I have a file and there is a number (x) into it, for example 1:

```
$x = fgets($number);
echo $x;
```

`1` is the output

now I want to compare that number with another number:

```
$x = fgets($number);
$y = 1;
if ($x == $y)
  echo "O.K";
else
  echo "not O.K";
```

But the output is `not O.K.`

Any idea why this is so?

Comment: Pass a filename under fgets("file.txt",r+) , not just a number.

Comment: Do $x = fgets($number); echo '$x = '; var_dump($x); echo ' ',PHP_EOL; $y = 1; echo '$y = '; var_dump($y); echo ' ',PHP_EOL; if ($x == $y) echo "O.K"; else echo "not O.K";

Comment: @sh4nx0r - that will give all manner of errors, suggest you read up on the syntax for fgets() - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

Comment: I've been code golfing too much.  `echo ((int)fgets($number)?'':'not ').'O.K';`

Answer (score 2):

If you use [`fgets`](http://php.net/fgets) to read something from a file, then the resulting string will include the trailing linebreak. (As there typically is one for text files.)

Either use [`trim`](http://php.net/trim):

```
$x = trim(fgets(STDIN));
```

Or a typecast:

```
$x = intval(fgets($fh));
```

For debugging always use [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var_dump) on variables which do not lead to expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the rest of the code, I'd guess it's because `$number` isn't a valid file handle, and therefore `fgets()` returns boolean `FALSE` which would equate to `0`.

Comment: I'm going to respectfully disagree with this.  In the first snippet, he outputs the result of `$x` directly, which shows "1".  If `$number` wasn't a valid handle, `$x` would be FALSE which doesn't actually output a character when echo'd.  Because it has output (and not a screen full of error messages) we can assume that the fgets executed properly.

Answer (score 1):

fgets grabs a line from the file with the newline still attached.  There's a good chance that might be messing things up.  Try the following:

```
$x = intval( fgets($number) );
$y = 1;
if ($x == $y)
  echo "O.K";  // Removed )

else
  echo "not O.K";  // Removed )
```

Note that using `==` instead of `===` means that the string "1" is considered equal to the number 1.  If you want to make sure that both the value *and* the types match, use `===`.

Answer (score 0):

Treat string as integrer:

if ((int)$x == $y)